# Why java division for integer is faster than hacker's delight implementation

Tags: java, math, latency, intrinsics

I am testing divs10 function throughput from hacker's delight book, coded in java on my jdk 1.7 64bit version 21 and i7 intel box
processor   : 7
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         920  @ 2.67GHz

I am wondering why the default java operator / is faster than divs10 function from hacker's delight book, the result shows divs10 is 3 times slower than "/" operator, to my surprise.

anybody can tell me if there is any fancy intrinsic jvm can be using?

source code as below.

```
 public class div10 {

            public static final int divs10(int n) {
                   int q, r;

                   n = n + (n >> 31 & 9);
                   q = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2);
                   q += q >> 4;
                   q += q >> 8;
                   q += q >> 16;
                   q = q >> 3;
                   r = n - ((q << 3) + (q << 1));
                   return q + ((r + 6) >> 4);
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                /*
                long count = 0;
                for (int i = Integer.MIN_VALUE; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                    if ( (i/10) != divs10(i) ) {
                        System.err.println("error dividing :" + i );
                    }
                    if ((i & 0xFFFFFFF ) == 0 ) {
                        System.out.println("Finished:" + Long.toHexString(count) + ":" + count + ":" + i);
                    }
                    count++;
                }

                System.out.println("Success:" + count);
                */

                long start = System.nanoTime();
                long count = 0L;
                int iter = 100_000;
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
                    for (int i = -iter; i < iter; i++) {
                        count += (i/10);
                    }
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) 
                    for (int i = -iter; i < iter; i++) {
                        count += divs10(i);
                    }
                System.out.println(count + " warm up done ") ;


                start = System.nanoTime();
                count = 0L;
                for (int i = Integer.MIN_VALUE; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                    count += i/10;
                }
                System.out.println(count + ", took:" + (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000_000L + " ms, " + (System.nanoTime() - start) / ((long)Integer.MAX_VALUE - (long)Integer.MIN_VALUE) + " ns per ops" ) ;

                start = System.nanoTime();
                count = 0L;
                for (int i = Integer.MIN_VALUE; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                    count += divs10(i);
                }
                System.out.println(count + ", took:" + (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000_000L + " ms, " + (System.nanoTime() - start) / ((long)Integer.MAX_VALUE - (long)Integer.MIN_VALUE) + " ns per ops" ) ;

           }
    }
```

Comment: why do you expect `divs10` to be faster, exactly? You are trying to implement an ALU at the software level, which is never going to be faster than your hardware's ALU.

Comment: +1 For someone that comes up with a correct benchmark :)

Comment: The "fancy intrinsic" is likely to be...your CPU's division operation.  (Gasp!)

Comment: My guess is that the "hacker" version is a *minimum* of 10 major machine cycles, and very easily 4 times that many.  (The fact that the same operand is the source and destination of so many sequential steps is a major pipeline killer.)  While raw hardware integer division is inherently 2-4 times slower than multiplication, most modern processors manage to accelerate it pretty well, to where it likely only takes maybe 8 major cycles -- 32 worst case.  (Processors with independent multiply/divide units will do much better.)

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** When looking at the newer [Ivy Bridge table](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) (p. 174), I saw that all the latencies where 1. This means that my previous explanation was not correct.

An attempt in counting the instructions  that are executed in the `divs10` method is 27 (without overhead of function calling) instructions. You are having operations that require the previous one to be completed before the next one can start.  So that means that you should consider the latency of the instructions. According to the Ivy Bridge instruction table, all of the instructions involved have a latency of 1 clock cycle. This gives you a total of 27 clock cycles.

This in comparison with a single IDIV (8-bit) instruction. In the table, I can find that this takes about 20 clock cycles latency.

A raw estimation would give: 27 cycles / 20 cycles = 1.35 times slower. This does not agree with the results you have. I'm not an expert at this, but I think this is due to the fact that divisions with the IDIV instruction can run in parallel, because they are independent. The IDIV instruction has a throughput of 8 clock cycles. Which allows the CPU to optimize the instructions in that way that it can run about 4 divisions per 52 cycles (this is an estimation).

So, to perform 4 divisions with the bit-shifting algorithm, you would need 108 cycles, whereas the IDIV would need approximately 64 clock cycles. This gives: 108 / 52 = 2.1 times slower.

This gets close to the ratio you measured. I guess that the remaining extra time goes to overhead of function calling. Maybe CPU's do greater optimizations than my estimation.

Comment: And it should be pointed out that because the result of one step is almost always the input to the next step, the ability of the CPU to "pipeline" and overlap successive instructions is virtually nil.

Comment: @HotLicks: Is it because the operations require the previous operation to finish, that the latency is really there?

Comment: In general, a modern CPU (other than the most primitive) will attempt to start a new instruction as soon as all inputs for it are available and the needed processing units (adder, shifter, etc) are available.  The above code sequence makes that pretty much impossible, since the input is taken from the immediately prior instruction.

Comment: Hot Licks, are you suggesting making more temp variables for divs10 shifting function will allow bitshifting being pipelined?

Comment: @porkchop: Nope, not at all. I don't think that your code can be better optimized. Also, modern CPU's are doing instruction reordering to pipeline as much as possible. Also, effort is made by the CPU to make computations run in parallel if possible.

Comment: make sense, also JIT may not be that smart to work with CPU for the pipline.

Comment: @porkchop: I revamped my answer. This is hopefully more precise.

Comment: @HotLicks: I revamped my answer. Do you think this is right? I want some feedback on this.

Comment: Modern CPU's have multiple specialized ALU units.  I'd expect the CPU to be able to do 3-4 `IDIV` instructions completely concurrently *(ie. if their inputs don't depend on each other, you should be able to get 3-4 `IDIV`'s done in 20 cycles)*.  Also there shouldn't be any function-overhead in this case, as the JVM will almost certainly inline it.

Comment: Also the JVM can unroll `count += (i/10)` better than `count += divs10(i)`, due to the function-inlining.  So there are *many* reasons to expect the first to be faster.

Comment: Martijn, I thought it was fine before.  Any estimates based on instruction timings and not accompanied by a *very* detailed analysis of inputs, pipeline delays, cache conflicts, et al are doing pretty good if they can come within a factor of two of "reality".

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - There is a wide variation between different processors, and I have no idea where the above unit falls.  But most units I've seen (though I've not kept up with the latest) cannot seriously overlap divides (though some can overlap multiplies).  A divide is inherently 2-4x as complex as a multiply and is quite a bit less frequent, so there's both less opportunity to speed up divide and less motivation.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Loop unrolling sounds interesting,  anyway to prove your jvm theory?

Comment: @porkchop: Look at the ASM the JVM outputs.

Comment: @Martijn Corteaux, I think the remaining ratio between 3 and 1.35, which is about 2.2, is due to the method invocation overhead. Indeed, when invoking a method, whether it was JITted or not, the JVM has first to access the Constant Pool and resolve the name of the method. At that point, either a JITted version of the method or its bytecode to interpret will be invoked. The only operation of accessing the CP is much slower than JVM opcodes like idiv to perform maths operation, as they're resolved immediately, without accessing things somewhere from memory.

Comment: And that's apparently making the whole division over two times slower, regardless of the number of generated Assembly instructions.

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
count += (i/10);
```

The Java JIT is able to optimize the division per a constant using some nice tricks, like "*Reciprocal Multiplication*" - see [this article for mathematical reference](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/1430) - or [this one](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/divide.html).

So it may be able to replace this division by a single multiplication + shift, which is in all cases, much faster than the circumvented `divs10()` function, which may be fast with oldest CPUs, but is not with modern CPUs, for which an integer multiplication take 1 or 1.5 cycle! The "hacker's delight" trick did play nicely with a plain 386, but not with modern CPus.

Furthermore, the JIT may be able to unroll the loop, for even faster process, since computing `count += ...` is easily paralleled.

Conclusion: when you work with a high-level language like Java, running on a VM with a JIT, do not expect to tell how the code would be compiled. Even any modern C compiler is able to optimize `count += i/10` by using the "*Reciprocal Multiplication*" trick, or unroll the loop (even make it multi-threaded).

Let your (JIT) compiler do its work, and, if performance is not enough for you, optimize your data structures and algorithms rather than trying to "tweak" the compiler. If you want some documentation and source code of low-level performance tricks at CPU level, [take a look at this reference material](http://www.agner.org/optimize/). But be aware that you won't be able to use those with Java (adding asm needs a C/C++ or Delphi compiler). Last but not least, remember that *Premature optimization is the root of all evil* (Knuth).

Comment: This is wrong, AFAIK. Reciprocal multiplication is only applicable if the compiler can guarantee that the division will be perfect (the number to be divided is an actual multiple of the divisor), which obviously isn't the case as `i` can be anything.

Comment: You are confusing reciprocal multiplication in "pure math", and its application in computer science. When applied to computing with fixed binary precision, it uses the automatic rounding by 32-bit or 64-bit to compute the actual exact value, whatever `i` is.  Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Division_by_a_constant *"division by 10 can be expressed as a multiplication by 3435973837 (0xCCCCCCCD) followed by division by 2^35 (or 35 right bit shift)"*

Comment: You are right! I forgot about this multiplicative trick! Thanks for pointing this out. I was indeed thinking about `x * i mod 2^32 = x / d`, when `i * d = 1 mod 2^32`.